# Elixir : Pattern match a function if a map contains at least one integer key

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I want to achieve something like the below (which obviously does not work)

```
def f1(%{key => _}) when is_integer(key) do :error end
def f1(%{}) do :ok end
```

I could match a map in the function head and check for an integer key inside the function body. Just wondering if there is a better approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, this can't be done with pattern matching. Here's how I'd implement it using the method you described:

```
def f1(%{} = map) do
  if map |> Map.keys() |> Enum.any?(&is_integer/1), do: :error, else: :ok
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also ended up doing something similar. Also I figured we cannot use a custom guard for this as we are limited in what we can use inside a guard clause

Answer (score 2):

While it’s impossible per se, one might slightly improve the performance by generating the clauses when possible integer values are known in advance. Also,  [`Kernel.map_size/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#map_size/1), which is allowed in guards, will be required:

```rb
defmodule NoIntegerKeys do
  defmacro __using__(name: name, disallowed: enum, do: block) do
    [
      (quote do: def unquote(name)(%{} = map) when map_size(map) == 0, do: :ok) |

      Enum.map(enum, fn i ->
        quote do
          def unquote(name)(%{unquote(i) => _}), do: :error
        end
      end)
    ] ++ [
      (quote do: def unquote(name)(%{} = map), do: unquote(block))
    ]
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use NoIntegerKeys, name: :f1, disallowed: [0,1,2], do: :ok
end

Test.f1(%{}) 
#⇒ :ok
Test.f1(%{foo: :bar})
#⇒ :ok
Test.f1(%{:foo => :bar, 3 => :baz})
#⇒ :ok

# BUT
Test.f1(%{:foo => :bar, 2 => :baz})
#⇒ :error
```

This example is a bit contrived, but it shows how one fight for the performance when it’s really needed. Macros are expanded by the compiler, so the resulting code would declare 5 different clauses: one for an empty map, three for possible values and the last one for the default execution block.